# Access jquery accordion with an external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used Jquery UI accordion in my page and it is working as expected.

I need to open the accordion panel with an external link which is a drop-down. How can I access accordion even with the drop-down list menu.

Here is what I have done so far

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Add list menu
    $('.droplist > li').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });

    //Accordion
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
          collapsible: true,
          active: false,
          heightStyle: "content"
        });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/citucoweli/2/edit)**

***PS***: HTML format can not be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the HTML cannot be change, you can try this:

```
$('.droplist > li > ul > li').on('click', function(){
    index = $(this).index();
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", index );
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/bowagozava/2/edit?html,js,output)

**Reference**

[.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

[accordion - option](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-option)

Comment: Thank you! One doubt, what if the dropdown list order ios like this `.droplist > li > ul > li > ul > li`     [http://jsbin.com/bojufurixu/2/]

Comment: If the links are not fitting to the corresponding tabs within the accordion, classes for reference would be better, otherwise you have to be careful with the use of the index

Comment: yeah did the same. I used a class name for the child ul

Answer (score 0):

I may be mis-understanding the problem, but to me you are asking how to automatically open the first accordion item?

```
$('#accordion li a').first().trigger('click');
```

This will trigger the first accordion item to open.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mogihuruya/1/)